# Как создать новый объект в окне(Android studio) через java код, и как определить касание двух объектов друг друга

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

Не так давно начал изучать android разработку на java. Мне захотелось создать свою симуляцию 
в android'е. Столкнулся с проблемой создания объекта через java код, то есть создавать пиксельную матрицу в xml разметки не хотелось, по плану было добавлять через java код картинку, и передвигать ее. я попытался просто создать пременную типа ImageView:

```
ImageView firstGameBot = new ImageView();
```

но это не сработало, он хотел чтобы я указал id этого елемента в xml странице.

и вторая проблема мне надо как то фиксировать столкновение двух существ между собой, единственное что мне приходит в голову это создать какой нибудь box колайдер как в Unity,но яне знаю как можно это реализовать и потом проверять их столкновение.

Заранее спасибо за все ответы.

Comment: Самый простой вариант, не прибегая к движкам таким как Unity, это рисование на View.Canvas, если нужна большая производительность, SurfaceView.Canvas

Comment: Возможно ли использовать картинку? и как отмечать столкновение двух объектов?

Comment: Да, вы можете отрисовать Bitmap на Canvas. https://www.gamedev.net/tutorials/_/technical/game-programming/collision-detection-r735/